# Document library keeps forgetting its settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning

I have a document library on a SPO site which I need to customize.

I want it to have the following settings:

- Require content approval for submitted items?  **Yes**
- Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?  **No**
- Display this list using the new or classic experience?  **Classic experience**

I can make these changes, and they work for a few minutes.  However, after a little while, the settings always revert back to their default values (no content approval, checkout required, default experience for the site).

Is there a way to "lock" these settings in place so that they won't be changed?  If not, is there any way to access a record of who or what is changing these settings, so I can figure out what's going on?  Maybe some admin is running an automated process across the tenant that makes these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, I couldn't reproduce your problem. After I set the configuration, SharePoint will automatically retain my settings and will not revert back to their default values.

You can run the below powershell command as an admin to define library settings.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$LibraryName = "XXX"
 
#Connect to Site collection from PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Enable Content Type
Set-PnPList -Identity $LibraryName -EnableContentTypes $True

Set-PnPList -Identity $LibraryName -ForceCheckout $false

Set-PnPList -Identity $LibraryName -ListExperience ClassicExperience
```

If you still have a similar situation after running the powershell command, I suggest you open a service request on the [Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/) to get more professional help.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it anymore either, it only happened for a few hours.  I'm blaming (*waves hands inarticulately*) "caching."

Comment: Hi, A_S00. Indeed, caching may cause this phenomenon to occur.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are changing all of the above settings with a SPO Admin account, or at least an account that has Owner permissions.

You could try changing the settings by utilising a PowerShell Script, an example of which you can find [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/versioning-settings-for-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/)

But, since you have seen some strange behaviour in your tenant, best you can do is open a ticket with MS. Unfortunately, they are the ones that might provide a better answer as to what is happening, since its a SaaS product.

Comment: Yes, I'm both a site collection admin and owner of the site (also have the global SharePoint Admin Azure role, though I doubt that matters for this case).  At the moment the settings have remained on the correct values for about an hour - I'm knocking on wood and hoping it was just a transient caching issue.  If it happens again, I'll try changing the settings using PowerShell, and if that doesn't work reach out to MS as you suggest.

Comment: hate to break it down, but your case reminded me of the below case reported on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/iyb5it/sharepoint_site_collection_storage_keeps_resetting/

Unfortunately, theres not much that we can do and a ticket to MS might be the best option.